# Compute the complex number $\cos \left(\frac\pi4 + \frac\pi4i\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Without a calculator or computer.

Hint: Consider expressions for $e^{\pm \theta i}$

i know that i cannot use a calculator or computer and that $\cos xy = \cos x\cos y - \sin x\sin y$ ive tried using $e^{\pm ix}$ is $\cos x\pm i\sin x$

this is supposed to be done without a calculator nor computer and must have a simple trick which im not sure about also we dont use use $\cosh$ or $\sinh$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: An alternative: The sum formula $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$ works even when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex. Also remember that $\cos it=\cosh t$, $\sin it= i\sinh t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer I have using the identities $$\cos (x+iy) = \cos x \cos iy - \sin x \sin iy$$ and $$\cos (ix) = \cosh x , \sin (ix) = i \sinh (x)$$ is $$\frac {\sqrt 2}{2} (\cosh \pi/4 + i \sinh \pi/4).$$

However, I can also use the identities $$\cosh (x) = \frac {e^x+e^{-x}}{2},\text { }\sinh (x) = \frac {e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$ and get $$\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}(1+i)(e^{\pi/4}+e^{-\pi/4})$$ in terms of $e^x.$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes $\pm$ is not your friend.

The hint was to consider expression**s** (more than one expression)
for $e^{\pm \theta i}$.
There are two expressions you already know.
If you write each of them individually rather than encoding both
of them with $\pm$ as if they were one expression, you get this:

\begin{align}
e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x, \\
e^{-ix} =\cos x - i\sin x.
\end{align}

Now remember you are trying to evaluate $\cos x$ where $x$ is a known value.

Comment: yeah i already did that, i don't know where to go from here though?

Comment: i tried and ended up with cancelling the isinx on the two simaltenous equations and eneded up with cosx = 1/2(e^((2pi^2)/16)+e^((pi*i/4)+pi/4)

Comment: At some point in your calculation, in order to evaluate $\cos \left(\frac\pi4 + \frac\pi4i\right)$ you will want to make the substitution $x = \frac14 + \frac14 i,$ won't you? When  you do that, what powers of $e$ do you get? Surely not the ones in the comment above!